# postgresql last insert id concurrency

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert an user and get its id e.g. last insert id. through sql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(registration_ip inet)
  RETURNS integer AS
insert into users(registration_ip)
   values($1);
select max(id) from users;
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

Is this function secure ? I meant is it concurrency safe ? e.g. n users are being created concurrently is it guaranteed that it will return the current user's id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(registration_ip inet)
  RETURNS integer AS
INSERT INTO users(registration_ip)
   VALUES($1) RETURNING id;
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Thanks. Really Simple Solution.

Answer (score 1):

No it's **not** safe (and it's terribly slow!)

You should use sequences for this purpose.

If the id column is defined as serial, a sequence is automatically created for you and you can retrieve the last generated number using `currval('users_id_seq')`.